How to Wrap ActiveRecord attr_encrypted Setter without Causing Infinite Loop in Ruby on Rails
I’m working with a Rails application that uses the attr_encrypted gem to handle encryption for sensitive data. Previously, we only stored the last 4 digits of the SSN. We’re migrating to store the full SSN while keeping the last 4 digits accessible as ssn_last_four for legacy compatibility.
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  prepend SsnLastFourConcern

  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'some_secret_key'
  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'some_secret_key'
end

and I have the concern:
module SsnLastFourConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def ssn_last_four
    return ssn[-4..] if ssn?
    super
  end

  def ssn=(value)
    self.ssn_last_four = value[-4..] if value.present? && value.length == 9
    super(value)
  end
end

The issue is that calling super(value) in the overridden ssn= setter leads to an infinite loop. But calling the super in ssn_last_four it works as expected
The workaround could be to use the before_save callback on ssn_last_four and make sure it reflects SSN. Also, by overriding the getter, the rest of the app will work properly, but I want to make sure that in case someone gets encrypted data from the column and manually decrypts it, he still gets the valid data.
EDIT: I do not override the ssn_last_four setter.
EDIT: Removed extend ActiveSupport::Concern as @engineersmnky suggested
Here is the stack trace:
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from ruby-2.7.8/gems/activemodel-6.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute_set.rb:33:in `key?'

why are you setting self.ssn_last_four in the ssn setter? that's where you are getting your loop

I want to update the value in that column as well, in case someone directly accesses it.

Please [edit] your question and add the stacktrace of the error (you can remove the repeating parts, but add enough to show exactly where it loops). Also, please make sure that you have shown all relevant code, including e.g. an overwritten ssn_last_four= setter.

you need a third attribute

As an aside there is no reason to extend ActiveSupport::Concern since you don't use any part of the Concern interface.
